# Rule of rational powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to show that the following rules hold for rational exponents:

1. $a^{n+m} = a^na^m$
2. $(a^n)^m = a^{nm}$

The first I was able to prove, but the second I've spent some time on without much progress. The only possibly useful observation has so far been that $a^{\frac{m}{n}} = (a^{\frac{1}{n}})^m$. I have shown the rules to work for natural and integral exponents.

**Question**. Let $a>0,m, n\ne 0, p, q\ne 0$ be integers. How to prove that:

$$
(a^{\frac{m}{n}})^{\frac{p}{q}} = a^{\frac{mp}{nq}}
$$

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I hope you also require $a>0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The rules do check out with $a=0$, but I think I see why negative $a$ will be problematic. I'll add that condition.

Comment: If $a$ is negative the $a^q; q\in \mathbb Q$ is not defined.  What is $(-4)^{\frac 32}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $a^{\frac{mp}{nq}}$ is the unique positive number whose $(nq)$th power is $a^{mp}$. To verify that $(a^{m/n})^{p/q}$ is equal to $a^{\frac{mp}{nq}}$, we can raise the former to the $(nq)$th power and see if it equals $a^{mp}$. Note that $(a^{m/n})^{p/q}$ is the unique number whose $q$th power is $(a^{m/n})^p$.
$$\begin{align*}
\left((a^{m/n})^{p/q}\right)^{nq} &= \left(\left(\left(a^{m/n}\right)^{p/q}\right)^q\right)^n& (*)\\
&= \left(\left(a^{m/n}\right)^p\right)^n\\
&= \left( \left(a^{m/n}\right)^n\right)^p &(*)\\
&= \left( a^m\right)^p\\
&= a^{mp}.
\end{align*}$$
The steps $(*)$ can be done because the exponents $q$, $n$, and $p$ are integers, and we do know that for *integer* exponents, $(a^r)^s = a^{rs} = (a^s)^r$.

Since the $(nq)$th power of $(a^{m/n})^{p/q}$ is equal to $a^{mp}$, it follows that $(a^{m/n})^{p/q}$ is equal to $a^{mp/nq}$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the edit; it confused me a bit initially :) Good to see that cleared up.